Which figure of speech is used in 'pull of dna'?
Adoptive motherhood is born of a psychical bond that is
so overpowering that it completely eclipses all received notions about ‘blood relation’, ‘pull of DNA’, etc.

A metaphor, I would say.

What do you think "pull of DNA" means in this context? You presumably have a better idea than us because you've read the entire text.

@StuartF I think it is a metaphor for "the influence (pull) one's genes (DNA) have on a individual."

@user405662 I think Stuart was asking a rhetorical question to the OP, to help them answer their own question.

I'd go with metonymy: using an obviously related element to stand for the tenor. 'Boil a kettle' = 'boil the water in a kettle'. 'The pull of DNA' = 'the draw of [a person] desiring to know who one's parents were'. Of course, 'pull/draw' has a primary sense in the physics domain, so there's metaphor involved as well.

Here's the source. It's not about the desires of the adopted child - it's about the adoptive mothers who choose motherhood with or without biological challenges either ignoring the biology part of it or transcending it. Essentially the claim is that if blood is thicker than water, then adoptive motherhood urges / ties are even stronger than those of biological parenthood. Which sounds like New Age tosh to me, but what do I know?
